# Which Drupal module to use for two-way referencing nodes (to each other)

Tags: drupal, reference, module

There are a lot of modules that enable two-way referencing nodes to each other. In the descriptions I read about those modules, they do not functionally seem to differ from each other. The modules I found are:

- Reverse Node Reference
- Corresponding Node References
- Node Relationships
- BackReference
- Node Referrer

You can find links to these modules on the Merge Blog: [10 small but usefull Drupal modules - Part 2](http://blog.merge.nl/2010/06/03/10-small-but-useful-drupal-modules-part-2/) *(Due to spam restrictions I can't post more than 1 link, so I can't link to the modules directly).*

Which module to choose? Are some modules better than others? How do they differ from each other?

Can anyone tell me where to find a decent description of these modules with their pre's and con's and maybe screenshots of how the interface is or what it takes to set up two way node referencing?

Comment: This is a rather vague question. You should tell us what exactly you're trying to do so we can give you answers specific to your situation rather than generalized answers that may or may not apply to you.

Comment: I want to add a project on a portfolio website. I want to select the related client with this project node. However, I also want to be able to add on or more project nodes when I add/edit the client node.

As long as it is not possible to add a node (inline) when adding a parent node, users have to add 2 nodes seperately first, and then link one node to another. 

I don't know if users prefer adding a project and then selecting a client, or if they want to add a client and then selecting projects with that client (it depends on the use case), so I want them to have both ways as an option.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a discussion from the "Similar Module Review" group that goes over some of the differences: 
http://groups.drupal.org/node/25554

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for all of the modules on that list but I've been using Corresponding Node References for a couple months now with much success. It's simple to setup and just works.